# Django max_length where there should not be a max_length

Tags: django

I do not have a deep understanding of Django, anyway not deep enough to overcome a problem that turns up in my application.

In models.py I have a.o. the following definitions:

```
class Relatiedata(models.Model):
    ...
    getuigen = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'relatiedata'

Relatiedata.objects = Relatiedata.objects.using('genealogie')
```

So in the database `genealogie`, which is not the default database, I have a table `relatiedata` with a column `getuigen` that has to contain a text string without a limitation on the length.

Further, I have a user form for mutating records of this table. As usual, the form is populated from a `Relatiedata.object` and the returned form results in another `Relatiedata.object` which is saved, thereby updating the database. This works (almost) perfect.

The problem is that in my form it turns out to be impossible to enter a string of length above 600 in the textarea for `getuigen`. Longer strings are simply cut off. There seems to be sort of a form validation for the length of that field, despite the fact that there is no such limit in the models, nor in the database, nor in the migration files.

This value of 600 comes from earlier, abandoned, implementations of the model, where originally I had a `CharField` with `max_length` 600 instead of a `TextField`.

All remarks are highly welcome.

**EDIT**

Some additional information. As it is now, the models were created from the already existing database, which is a simple sqlite database with some tables, no relations between the tables. The table `relatiedata` is a simple table with some textual columns, a little bit too large to show here. `Makemigrations` and `migrate` were of course used after the models were constructed, and at the moment makemigrations does not find anything to migrate.

Even worse: when I change the definition:

```
getuigen = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True),
```

`makemigrations` shows this change and `migrate` solves it, but it is still impossible to use a string of more than 600 characters in the form. With less, it is OK.

Finally, I can change the value of the field `getuigen` to strings with more than 600 characters by using `SQL`. Having done that, in my application the long string turns up correctly in all output where it should be, even in my mutation form. But in the mutation form it cannot be edited because it is too long.

Comment: did you do makemigrations and migrated

Comment: which DB do you use ? can you post the Relatiedata table from that DB?

Comment: @iklinac: yes, but that did not help, Please see the edit.

Comment: @barbaart1: it is a bit too large to post it here, but it seems to work fine. Please see my edit.

Comment: @FredSimons , Did you alter the column mannually like this? ALTER TABLE <YourTable> ALTER COLUMN <YourColumn> VARCHAR (2000);

Comment: @barbaart1: In my database the data type of the column is (according to SQLiteStudio) TEXT. Following your suggestion, I changed this manually to VARCHAR(2000). That did not help. In my mutation form I still experience a limit of 600 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make migrations and migrate again

```
python manage.py makemigrations specify_app_name
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate specify_app_name
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but in vain. Please see my edit.